# getting nullpointerexception while mocking webclient post method .body

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, spring-webclient

getting nullpointerexception while mocking webclient post method

```
public class RepoService {
@Autowired
private WebClient webClient;

public DIResponse createIdentity(DICreateRequest diCreateRequest) {
        CreateReq createReq = diCreateRequestMapper.setRequest(diCreateRequest);
        DIResponse diResponse = null;

        UriComponents uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromUriString(url)
                .build(false);

        DIResponse apiResponse = webClient
                .post()
                .uri(uriBuilder.toUriString())
                .body(Mono.just(createReq), CreateReq.class)  // getting nullpointer exception here
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(DIBadRequest.class).flatMap(errorResponse -> {
                    LOGGER.error(CLIENT_ERROR, "POST", clientResponse.statusCode(), errorResponse);
                    return Mono.error(new DataAccessException(ERROR_STATUS +clientResponse.statusCode()+ ERROR_DESC+ errorResponse.getDetail()));
                }))
                .bodyToMono(DIResponse.class)
                .block();

return apiResponse
 }
}
```

Below is my Mockito junit test case

```
@Mock
    private WebClient webClient;

    @Mock
    WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec requestHeadersUriSpecMock;
    @Mock
    WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec requestBodyUriSpecMock;

    @Mock
    WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestBodySpecMock;

    @Mock
    WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec requestHeadersSpecMock;

    @Mock
    WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpecMock;

@InjectMocks
    private RepoService repositoryService;

@Test
    void testCreateIdentity() throws IOException {
        

        DICreateRequest mockDICreateRequest = getMockDICreatReq();
        CreateReq createReq = createDI();
        DIResponse mockDIResponse = getDI();

when(diCreateRequestMapper.setRequest(mockDICreateRequest)).thenReturn(createReq);

when(webClient.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpecMock);
when(requestBodyUriSpecMock.uri((URI) any())).thenReturn(requestBodySpecMock);
when(requestBodySpecMock.body(any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpecMock);
when(requestHeadersSpecMock.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpecMock);
when(responseSpecMock.onStatus(any(), any())).thenReturn(responseSpecMock);
Mockito.when(responseSpecMock.bodyToMono(DIResponse.class)).thenReturn(Mono.just(mockDIResponse));

        DIResponse result = repositoryService.createIdentity(mockDICreateRequest);

        Assert.assertEquals(mockDIResponse.getId(), result.getId());
    }
```

createReq is not null but  getting nullpointer exception here **.body(Mono.just(createReq), CreateReq.class)**

I thought it would be serialization error, so I tried like below

```
String req = //request object to string
.body(req, String.class)
```

still it is giving nullpointer exception

Comment: Make sure to include the stacktrace

Comment: In the line `when(requestBodyUriSpecMock.uri((URI) any())).thenReturn(requestBodySpecMock);` you are casting `any()` to `URI`. I believe the correct way to mock for a specific parametertype is using `any(URI.class)` instead of casting.

Comment: Thank you! for the suggestion. I am getting nullpointer exception for this line .body(Mono.just(createReq), CreateReq.class)

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in the second response? If your mock at `.uri` fails to apply, it would lead to a NPE at `.body`, which is consistent with what you describe.

Comment: Yes, I have implemented the same but still it is giving NPE at .body.
And also in my RepoService class ,
UriComponents uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromUriString(url)
                .build(false);
 url is added from properties like 
@Value("${proxy.url}")
    private String url;

Comment: in test class Iam setting the url by using Field like below
            'Field field = targetObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(targetObject, value);'

Comment: in your service, you have `.uri(uriBuilder.toUriString())`, yet you are mocking for a parameter being URI.class. You could try changing the mock for this to: `when(requestBodyUriSpecMock.uri(any(String.class))).thenReturn(requestBodySpecMock);`

Comment: Thank you! it passed the .body but now NPE is at .retrieve()

Comment: That's because you mocked the `.body`-method which accepts one parameter. Instead mock with `.body(any(), eq(CreateReq.class))`

Comment: @ODDminus1, Thank You! it is working as expected.
Can you please help me creating the test cases for 
'.onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(DIBadRequest.class).flatMap(errorResponse -> {
                    LOGGER.error(CLIENT_ERROR, "POST", clientResponse.statusCode(), errorResponse);
                    return Mono.error(new DataAccessException(ERROR_STATUS +clientResponse.statusCode()+ ERROR_DESC+ errorResponse.getDetail()));
                }))'
test cases is not covering inside the onStatus, I tried many scenario but it is not

Comment: You're welcome. Your question here is outside of the scope of this question and a bit broad to help with in this discussion. I recommend creating a new question which details your issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you deal with 'fluent api' mocking problem. I actually stuck at it right now too. Here is a link that might help you to figure out some way to solve your problem:
[Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-fluent-apis)

Hope it will help you!